# Magento 1.9.2 server requirements

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

My magento site contains 5000 skus and large number of attributes. my client  wants to host in vps server. It contains total size of 5gb of data and 80 mb of sql data. No way to host in dedicated server.

I wants to know the  proccessor, Ram needed, Hard disk size, Bandwidth required to make my site speed.

Kindly let me know.

Comment: Bandwidth depends more on the hit-rate (number of visitors) rather than on actual size of content (although a large number of images will add an impact).

Comment: no.of visitors expect per day 100.. Image contains 3.8 gb of data

Answer (score 0):

A VPS with 2-3GHz CPU, 2GB of RAM, on HDDs (> 15GB) should do just fine even at peak usage.

Also consider using Varnish as a reverse proxy and static files cache.

Using varnish will:

- cache files for much faster delivery
- reuse connections to apache for multiple requests
- make peak usage impact less probable